# ggplot2 boxplot for two different interactions in one plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, boxplot

I'm new to R and ggplot2, sorry for asking about the basics.

I'm trying to put on one plot two kind of interactions: "size" sorted by "operculum" and and "mortality" sorted by "operculum". 
For each pair I use smth like this

```
p <- ggplot(lsr, aes(operculum, mortality), na.rm=TRUE)
p + geom_boxplot()
```

I tried to figure out how to combine it on one plot and did this

```
p <- ggplot(lsr, aes(operculum, mortality, fill=interaction(operculum,    size)))
p + geom_boxplot()
```

which didn't work out.

Ideally each of two interactions should have its own colour.
Another question - is it possible to somehow show on the plot which groups (in my case which operculums) differ significantly?

I have data imported from excel, which looks like this (in reality it's much bigger, this one is an example )

```
mortality    size        operculum
1   50.00000 34.482759      0,1p
2  100.00000 16.000000      0,1p
3  100.00000  5.128205      0,1p
4   40.00000  5.319149      0,1p
5   83.33333  8.450704      0,1p
6   45.45455 17.600000      0,1p
7    0.00000 27.586207     0,15p
8   90.00000 40.000000     0,15p
9   81.25000 41.025641     0,15p
10  44.82759 30.851064     0,15p
11  38.46154 36.619718     0,15p
12  23.91304 36.800000     0,15p
13  81.81818 14.666667     0,15p
14 100.00000 24.615385     0,15p
15  16.66667 20.689655      0,2p
16  70.00000 40.000000      0,2p
17  76.92308 33.333333      0,2p
18  12.30769 34.574468      0,2p
19  41.66667 33.802817      0,2p
20   6.25000 25.600000      0,2p
21  80.00000 33.333333      0,2p
22 100.00000 46.153846      0,2p
23  33.33333 16.363636      0,2p
24  33.33333 30.000000      0,2p
```

Thanks in advance and sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Is `ggplot(reshape2::melt(lsr, id.vars = 'operculum'), aes(x = operculum, y = value, colour = variable)) + geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge(width = .8))` what you want? I'm not sure which groups you want to compare. You mean the distributions of `mortality` and `size` for each level of `operculum`? And what do you want to do with that? a p-value above each box?

Comment: The resulting plot is exactly what I wanted, thank you)
as for the p-value - it only relates to the mortality/operculum level. I would like to show which levels differ significantly from each other. According to the paired t-test these are 0,1p, 0,15p, 0,2p (in the real data there are much more levels, but only these three have p-value<0,05). How can I mark only these three boxes? It can be a p-value written above them for example, or they can have different color inside

Comment: one option would be to add `+ annotate('text', x = 1:3, y = 100, label = c(.04, .1, .001))` or something similar, but this is hard-coded. do you need something more automated?